# Linear Regression y=A + Bc^x

Tags: regression

I want to do a regression in R (RStudio), with equation:

$ y = A + Bc^x$.

Any idea on how to do such regression? Thank You

Comment: That is not a linear regression so I think you need to do some more revision of your statistics course before actually attempting an analysis.

Comment: Is $c$ an unknown parameter to be estimated?

Comment: The first duplicate gives answers.  The others give answers to special cases of this regression and therefore can offer helpful ideas.  Of course, you need to recognize that by definition $c^x=\exp(x\log c).$  For more related posts, search our site for [nls exp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nls+exp).